# Can't get RadioButton state

Tags: android

I'm working with a `RadioGroup`. I have used the following code to implement a `RadioButton` inside an `AlertDialog`.

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
int checkedRadioButton = 0;
    try {
    checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
int i =0;
switch (checkedRadioButton) {
case R.id.a2s :
datasource.updateIcon(i,itemid);
break;
case R.id.android: i=1;
datasource.updateIcon(i,itemid);
break;
```

But the `checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();` throws a NullPonterException when called. Why is this happening?

```
02-29 07:30:30.514: W/System.err(13957): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 07:30:30.514: W/System.err(13957):    at com.manager.boot.r1223.OSListActivity$5.onClick(OSListActivity.java:219)
02-29 07:30:30.514: W/System.err(13957):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
02-29 07:30:30.514: W/System.err(13957):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-29 07:30:30.514: W/System.err(13957):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-29 07:30:30.514: W/System.err(13957):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-29 07:30:30.514: W/System.err(13957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 07:30:30.514: W/System.err(13957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-29 07:30:30.514: W/System.err(13957):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-29 07:30:30.514: W/System.err(13957):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-29 07:30:30.514: W/System.err(13957):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Android" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/a2s"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Argen2Stone ROM" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error happen here: `RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);`

your AlertDialog has using `setContentView` to the layout or not ?

Comment: Yes it does. `LayoutInflater seticonradiolist = LayoutInflater.from(this);
   final View radioGroupView = seticonradiolist.inflate(R.layout.seticon,
     null);
   new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
   .setTitle("Set icon for " + item_cursor.getString(1))
   .setView(radioGroupView)`

Comment: so, can you try comment `checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();` the code, just show the dialog, the dialog show right as you like?

Comment: sorry, from your comment and code, i cant find another problem, can you paste your dialog complete code

Comment: i find the error, the method `RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);` actually run in the activity not in your dialog, the activity layout dont have the `R.id.radiogroup` id element.

Comment: try use `radioGroupView.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);` to instead of, but the radioGroupView must the final type.

Comment: so, suggestion use the inner class need carefully -):

Answer (score 0):

You should double check your layout. Either `R.id.radiogroup` does not exist in the current view you are looking at, or it is not of type `RadioGroup`.

Comment: `R.id.radiogroup` exists and It is of type `RadioGroup`. Check the edit with layout.